# Is there a way to add tags to automated AWS Redshift snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-redshift

My question is pretty straightforward - can you attach a list of tags to the automated cluster snapshots that AWS will take for a cluster?

Some background, when we manually create snapshots, we upload a series of tags along with the CreateClusterSnapshot request that allow us to associate snapshots with users (therefore giving them the ability to resume a redshift cluster from a 'terminated' instance at a later date. Unfortunately, automated snapshots (enabled via the withAutomatedSnapshotRetentionPeriod setting) arrive in aws untagged, and therefore we have no way of associating them with an end user beyond manually adding the tags.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to add tags _after_ the automated snapshot is created, or are you wanting to add them _when_ the automated snapshot is created?

Comment: The latter. We have a set of tags associated with the cluster - I would like to apply a subsection of those tags to the images so that they can be matched to the same owner, for instance.

Comment: I doubt that you can specify tags for automated snapshots, but you should be able to add tags _after_ the snapshot is made. As to _how_ to do that, not sure but perhaps a Lambda function on a schedule (or possibly triggered from a snapshot) that adds tags after-the-fact.

Comment: Not sure if you are using Terraform. But Terraform gives the option of "copy_tags_to_snapshot" again unfortunately this is not there for Redshift as of now. You might have to raise a issue or request on Github

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19279

Hope it helps

Comment: modify-snapshot-copy-retention-period for Redshift, doesn't give to option to add tags either


https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/modify-snapshot-copy-retention-period.html

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the answers, appreciate you taking the time to get back to me.

Answer (score 2):

No way to do it in Terraform at the moment. I put in a request to AWS for them to add this feature to redshift. You would think you would be able to just check a box if you want to add cluster tags to automated snapshots.

1. Automated Snapshots don't produce a cloudtrail log so you can't do this event driven(from my knowledge), it has to a cron job that runs every so often looking for snapshots.

   ```
    import json
    import boto3

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        client = boto3.client('redshift')
        response = client.describe_cluster_snapshots()

    for i in range(len(response["Snapshots"])):

        #Count number of Tags assoicated with Snapshot
        NumofTags = len(response["Snapshots"][i]["Tags"])

        #Get the name of the cluster the snapshot is for
        clustername = response["Snapshots"][i]["ClusterIdentifier"]

        #Create the ARN for the snapshot
        arn = "arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:631284890255:snapshot:" + clustername + "/" + str(response["Snapshots"][i]["SnapshotIdentifier"])


        #if snapshot has no tags get tags from cluster and append tags to snapshot
        if NumofTags == 0:

            try:

                #Get Cluster information
                cl_response = client.describe_clusters(ClusterIdentifier=clustername)

                #Get tags from cluster
                clustertags = cl_response["Clusters"][0]['Tags']

                #Append cluster tags to snapshot
                client.create_tags(ResourceName=arn,Tags=clustertags)

            #If cluster no longer exists print Exception and continue function    
            except:
                print("Cluster already destroyed: no tags to be assigned")
                continue



    return "Function Complete"
   ```

This is the lambda I wrote to check every snapshots for tags, if there are no tags, pull tags from cluster and add them. Exception for If the cluster had been destroyed already but snapshots were still present.